# OLEDB provider for linked server reported change of schema version between compile time and run time for table error

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008, oledb, linked-server

I am trying to run a report but its giving this message:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'ParamYear'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
```

I checked in Visual studio and I get this error:

```
    OLEDB provider for linked server sql10 reported change of schema version between 
compile time("182424452472301") and run time ("182454520418731") 
for table dbo.stud
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Funding_Type
FROM            Destinations_1415_1516_Union
WHERE        (Year IN (@Year)) AND (AgeBand IN (@AgeBand)) AND (Completion_Status IN (2, 3))
```

Kindly let me know how to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran dbcc freeproccache command in ssms and re-ran the report. Works fine now....